# creating a Placemarks that can be hidden

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth-plugin

I have been trying to create a Placemark that I can hide and show (like turning visibility on and off) on demand (on click)... I am using this to make the placemark:

```
function placemark(lat, long, name, url, iconsrc){
    var placemark = ge.createPlacemark(name);
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
    placemark.setName(name);

    // Create style map for placemark
    var icon = ge.createIcon('');
    if(iconsrc == "0")
        icon.setHref('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png');
    else{
        icon.setHref(iconsrc);
    }
    var style = ge.createStyle('');
    style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
    if(iconsrc != "0")
        style.getIconStyle().setScale(2.5);

    placemark.setStyleSelector(style);

    // Create point
    var point = ge.createPoint('');
    point.setLatitude(lat);
    point.setLongitude(long);
    //point.setAltitudeMode(1500);
    placemark.setGeometry(point);
    google.earth.addEventListener(placemark, 'click', function(event) {
    // Prevent the default balloon from popping up.
        event.preventDefault();

        var balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
        balloon.setFeature(placemark); // optional
        balloon.setContentString(
            '<iframe src="'+ url +'" frameborder="0"></iframe>');

        ge.setBalloon(balloon);
    });              

}
```

I have tried everything... from this:

```
function hidePlacemark(name){
    var children = ge.getFeatures().getChildNodes();
    for(var i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) { 
        var child = children.item(i);
        if(child.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
            if(child.getId()== name)
            child.setVisibility(false);
        }
    }
}
```

to using this `ge.getFeatures().removeChild(child);`

can anyone point me to the right direction on creating a function that will allow me to turn the visibility on/off on demand please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hidePlacemark function is missing some {} in your final IF statement

```
if(child.getId()== name)
```

you have

```
function hidePlacemark(name){
    var children = ge.getFeatures().getChildNodes();
    for(var i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) { 
        var child = children.item(i);
        if(child.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
            if(child.getId()== name)
            child.setVisibility(false);
        }
    }
}
```

make it

```
function hidePlacemark(name){
    var children = ge.getFeatures().getChildNodes();
    for(var i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) { 
        var child = children.item(i);
        if(child.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
            if(child.getId()== name) {
                child.setVisibility(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HOWEVER ------- you are better off doing this as it is much faster as you don't need to loop through ALL your placemarks

```
function hidePlacemark(name) {
    var placemark = ge.getElementById(name);
    placemark.setVisibility(false);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why I didn't think of doing that myself.. I've been stuck with this damn bug in this code for so long, I didn't even think to approach it differently... you're the man(or lady if you're one!)!

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer...It is also worth noting that kml visibility is hierarchical, so you can easily toggle sets of items by simply setting the visibility of the parent on/off.

Answer (score 1):

I think the plain `ge.getFeatures().removeChild(placemark);` works.

I played with this [GooglePlayground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#toggling_event_listeners), and just added the following code to line 8 (that is empty in this [GooglePlayground Sample](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#toggling_event_listeners)):

```
  addSampleButton('Hide Placemark', function(){ 
       ge.getFeatures().removeChild(placemark); 
  });
```

Clicking the button *Hide Placemark* hides the placemark like a charm here. Any chances your problem is somewhere else in your code?

Comment: The problem is that once you removeChild, you can't create the same placemark again because the uniqueID cannot be used twice... =\ that's what I meant by hidden... so that it can be "turned off" and "turned on" as needed.